# While migrating to angular v15.2.9, Custom CSS are throwing an error

Tags: angular, angular15, angular-migration

`I am very much new at these migration parts, while updating angular versions I am facing these issues.

> ./src/app/app.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> You probably don't mean to use the color value white in interpolation here.
> It may end up represented as white, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
> Always quote color names when using them as strings or map keys (for example, "white").
> If you really want to use the color value here, use '"" + $color'.
>
> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root.scss 4:9       @import
> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 11:9  @import
> src/styles.scss 7:9                              @import
> src/app/app.component.scss 1:9                   root stylesheet
>
> ./src/app/app.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> You probably don't mean to use the color value yellow in interpolation here.
> It may end up represented as yellow, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
> Always quote color names when using them as strings or map keys (for example, "yellow").
> If you really want to use the color value here, use '"" + $color'.
>
> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_root.scss 4:9       @import
> node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 11:9  @import
> src/styles.scss 7:9                              @import
> src/app/app.component.scss 1:9                   root stylesheet
>
> ./src/app/app.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> 1 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted.
> Run in verbose mode to see all warnings.
>
> null
>
> ./src/app/auth/reset-password/reset-password.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
>
> Recommendation: math.div(2em, 14) or calc(2em / 14)
>
> More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div
>
> node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_list.scss 14:9                 @import
> node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 12:9          @import
> src/styles.scss 9:9                                            @import
> src/app/components/navbar/navbar.component.scss 3:9            @import
> src/app/auth/reset-password/reset-password.component.scss 2:9  root stylesheet
>
> ./src/app/auth/reset-password/reset-password.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
>
> Recommendation: math.div(3em, 4) or calc(3em / 4)
>
> More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div
>
> node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_larger.scss 7:17               @import
> node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 10:9          @import
> src/styles.scss 9:9                                            @import
> src/app/components/navbar/navbar.component.scss 3:9            @import
> src/app/auth/reset-password/reset-password.component.scss 2:9  root stylesheet
>
> ./src/app/auth/reset-password/reset-password.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Deprecation Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
>
> Recommendation: math.div(4em, 3) or calc(4em / 3)
>
> More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div
>
> node_modules/font-awesome/scss/_larger.scss 6:15               @import
> node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss 10:9          @import
> src/styles.scss 9:9                                            @import
> src/app/components/navbar/navbar.component.scss 3:9            @import
> src/app/auth/reset-password/reset-password.component.scss 2:9  root stylesheet

this is my package.json

````
                {
                    "name": "anchor-ui",
                    "version": "0.0.0",
                    "scripts": {
                        "ng": "ng",
                        "start": "ng node --max_old_space_size=2192 serve ",
                        "build": "ng build",
                        "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
                        "test": "ng test",
                        "postinstall": "ngcc"
                    },
                    "private": true,
                    "dependencies": {
                        "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
                        "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/material": "^15.0.4",
                        "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
                        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
                        "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
                        "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
                        "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.5.7",
                        "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.37.0",
                        "@canvasjs/charts": "^3.7.10",
                        "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
                        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.1.0",
                        "@ng-idle/core": "^11.1.0",
                        "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^11.0.3",
                        "@ng-select/ng-select": "^10.0.4",
                        "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
                        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
                        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
                        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.0",
                        "@types/canvasjs": "^1.9.8",
                        "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^5.0.4",
                        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
                        "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
                        "compass-mixins": "^0.12.10",
                        "core-js": "^3.19.3",
                        "country-state-city": "^3.0.1",
                        "crypto-js": "\~3.3.0",
                        "datatables.net": "^1.13.2",
                        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
                        "jquery": "^3.7.0",
                        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
                        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
                        "moment": "^2.29.1",
                        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
                        "mouseleave": "^1.0.0",
                        "ng-idle": "^1.3.2",
                        "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.3.4",
                        "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
                        "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
                        "ngx-timeago": "^2.0.0",
                        "ngx-toastr": "^16.2.0",
                        "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
                        "node": "^18.16.1",
                        "node-modules": "^1.0.1",
                        "postcss-loader": "^7.3.2",
                        "rxjs": "\~7.4.0",
                        "sass": "^1.58.1",
                        "tslib": "^2.3.0",
                        "zone.js": "\~0.12.0"
                    },
                    "devDependencies": {
                        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
                        "@angular/localize": "^15.2.9",
                        "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
                        "@types/jasmine": "\~4.3.0",
                        "@types/jasminewd2": "\~2.0.8",
                        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
                        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.166",
                        "@types/node": "\~13.1.8",
                        "codelyzer": "\~5.2.1",
                        "jasmine-core": "\~4.1.0",
                        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "\~4.2.1",
                        "karma": "\~6.3.0",
                        "karma-chrome-launcher": "\~3.1.0",
                        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "\~2.1.1",
                        "karma-jasmine": "\~5.0.0",
                        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
                        "protractor": "\~7.0.0",
                        "ts-node": "\~8.6.2",
                        "tslint": "\~6.1.3",
                        "typescript": "\~4.8.0"
                    }
                }```

I need to resolve these CSS issues, ngbootstrap doesn't work in 15.2.9, is there any alternative?`
````